# How do I know the particular user who placed an order or make a request

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have been thinking about something, ( I'm new to Django) how do you get to know the user who is making a request or placing an order without having to ask them to fill a form for their username since they are logged in already

I have been thinking about something, ( I'm new to Django) how do you get to know the user who is making a request.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_request_function( 
    request: HttpRequest, 
    *args, **kwargs,
) -> HttpResponse: 
    
    user = request.user

    # some more code to compute the template to render and the context
    # the template if necessary

    return render( request, my_template, my_context, )
```